# Java operator errors

Tags: java, addition

I'm working on an assignment for my Java class and I keep getting compiler errors.

The errors I'm getting are "not a statement subtotal ++ total;" and "error: ';' expected
subtotal ++ total;".

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The assignment is to create a program that adds numbers together and prints the subtotal once the user enters a zero, and prints the complete total after two consecutive zeros.

I am using this website for the programming and compiling: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php

Thanks in advance.

```
public class Homework4{

 public static void main(String []args){

    int n;      
    int previous = -99999;      
    int total = 0;      
    int subtotal = 0;         

    System.out.println("This program will add numbers you input.");
    System.out.println("Once you input a number, press enter.");
    System.out.println("When you want the subtotal of your numbers, input 0.");
    System.out.println("When you want the complete total, input 0 once more.");

    n = scanner.nextInt ( );      
    while (true) {          
        if (n == 0 && previous == 0) {              
            System.out.println("Total: " + total);          
            } else if (n == 0) {             
                subtotal ++ total;         
                System.out.println("Subtotal: " +subtotal);
                subtotal == 0;              
                previous == 0;          
            } else {     
                n ++ subtotal;
                previous == n;              
                      }          
                n = scanner.nextInt ( );     
                }  


     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unary addition is not `++`. It is `+=`

```
subtotal += total;
```

is equivalent to

```
subtotal=subtotal+total;
```

and is a convenient shorthand.

To add 1 to a variable, use:

```
varToIncrement++;
```

Note there is nothing on the other side of the operator.

On that note I recommend that you install an IDE such as Eclipse, and the JDK, as a site like writecodeonline is less powerful and will not let you try your Java code to its full potential.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it runs great now. I'd like to use Eclipse but the only computer I have available to me right now is a chromebook.

Comment: @HectorBrass If this answer helped please click the grey checkmark to the left of it to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use += instead of ++.  ++ is to increment a counter not to add.
Query: what if user wants to add ten(10)? will the check on 0 work?